# Disable encoding of the pipe character on http request

Tags: java, http, jsoup

I am trying to send a request to an URL that uses the pipe character in its URL 
`site.com/page?param=|||`

Sending a request to this URL using both Jsoup and URLConnection causes the pipe character to be encoded to %7C, however, the site accept only unencoded `|`.

I have checked with fiddler, and noticed that Web browsers does not encode the pipe character, so why java libraries (the URI class i guess) has to encode it? 
and is there a way to force (or disable the encoding for that particular character) when sending the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a test,and send request by using `Jsoup` and `URLConnection`,i notice that the `URLConnection` is not encode the url. This is my test code:

```
Connection jsoupConnection = Jsoup.connect("http://www.baidu.com/page?param=|||");
Document document = jsoupConnection.get();
URL url=new URL("http://www.baidu.com/page?param=|||");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
InputStream input = urlConnection.getInputStream();
byte[] entity = ByteStreams.toByteArray(input);
```

And i monitor the internet with `WireShark`.This is http packet while using `Jsoup`:

```
10  0.011680000 192.168.78.128  115.239.210.27  HTTP    357 GET /page?param=%7C%7C%7C HTTP/1.1
```

this is `URLConnection`:

```
27  0.128714000 192.168.78.128  115.239.210.27  HTTP    220 GET /page?param=||| HTTP/1.1
```

So,the Url is not encoded while using `URLConnection`.

And i look the implemention of method `connect` in `Jsoup`,and found the key code:

```
private static URL encodeUrl(URL u) {
    try {
        //  odd way to encode urls, but it works!
        final URI uri = new URI(u.getProtocol(), u.getUserInfo(), u.getHost(), u.getPort(), u.getPath(), u.getQuery(), u.getRef());
        return new URL(uri.toASCIIString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return u;
    }
}
```

The url is encoded take place in `final URI uri = new URI(u.getProtocol(), u.getUserInfo(), u.getHost(), u.getPort(), u.getPath(), u.getQuery(), u.getRef());`,and there is no property to control the encoding or not in `Jsoup`.

So i think you can use the `URLConnection` rather than `Jsoup`.